# C++ templated linked list trouble

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have made a few linked lists before and the concepts all make sense to me, but for a project I have to make a templated one in C++, which I haven't used a whole lot, and I am having some trouble. Please help. I have spent far too much time on such a simple thing.

I have some of the list class already, but the problem lies somewhere in here. When I make three nodes in a test case and link them all up, if I call

```
node1.getNext().show();
```

That works fine, but if I

```
node1.getNext().getNext().show();
```

I get a segfault (core dumped). What is wrong here? I have tried changing the pointers on the return values of getNext() and getPrev() a bunch of times with no luck. I feel stupid asking this question, but I'm having some serious trouble. My node class is below, followed by a sample test case that gives a segfault.

Node.h:

```
template <class T> class Node
{
 public:
  Node();
  Node(T value);
  void setPrev(Node<T> node);
  void setValue(T value);
  void setNext(Node<T> node);
  Node<T> getPrev();
  T getValue();
  Node<T> getNext();
  void show();
  ~Node() { }

 private:
  Node<T> *prev;
  Node<T> *next;
  T value;
};

//default construct                                                                                                                                                     
template <class T> Node<T>::Node() {
  this->prev = NULL;
  this->value = NULL;
  this->next = NULL;
};

//overloaded construct                                                                                                                                                  
template <class T> Node<T>::Node(T value) {
  this->prev = NULL;
  this->value = value;
  this->next = NULL;
}

template <class T> void Node<T>::setPrev(Node<T> node) {
  this->prev = &node;
}

template <class T> void Node<T>::setValue(T value) {
  this->value = value;
}

template <class T> void Node<T>::setNext(Node<T> node) {
  this->next = &node;
}

template <class T> Node<T> Node<T>::getPrev() {
  return this->prev;
}

template <class T> T Node<T>::getValue() {
  return this->value;
}

template <class T> Node<T> Node<T>::getNext() {
  return this->next;
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::show() {
  cout << value << endl;
}
```

Test case:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  typedef Node<int> IntNode;

  IntNode head(NULL);
  IntNode node1(23);
  IntNode node2(45);
  IntNode node3(77);
  IntNode tail(NULL);
  node1.setPrev(head);
  node1.setNext(node2);
  node2.setPrev(node1);
  node2.setNext(node3);
  node3.setPrev(node2);
  node3.setNext(tail);

  node1.show();
  node2.show();
  node3.show();

  cout << node1.getNext().getValue() << endl;
  cout << node1.getNext().getNext().getValue() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you reimplementing `std::list` as a learning project?

Comment: instead on setPrev/setNext you should just implement append, and perform pointers linking inside. Otherwise the data hiding, that is the motivation of classes, it's ineffective, being the 'hard' logic handled outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass values by reference rather than by value.

When your `node1.setNext(node1)` is executed, `setNext()` gets a copy of `node1` on the stack, not the variable you define in `main()`. Once `setNext()` exits, the address stored in `next` is no longer valid.

For starters, redefine functions setPrev and setNext as

```
template <class T> void Node<T>::setPrev(Node<T> &node) {
  this->prev = &node;
}

template <class T> void Node<T>::setNext(Node<T> &node) {
  this->next = &node;
}
```

and that will fix your immediate segfaults. However, you really need to think more about design of your code and what happens when you pass by reference or by value, to write this correctly and avoid further problems.

Comment: Thanks so much. Like I said, I've only used C++ a few times before, so I'm not completely comfortable with pointers yet, but working on it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You should be storing your next/previous members as pointers. When you set your previous and next nodes you are taking the parameters by value and therefore copying.

This means when you step through to the second `.getNext()` in `node1.getNext().getNext().getValue()` you will encounter a dangling pointer, this is why your code is failing.

Adding nodes by hand is laborious, the way something like `std::list` works is by having a `begin` and `end` pointer to the collection it owns. When a new node is pushed on the front or back of the list the collection creates the node, stores the value and links up the pointers ready for the next node and/or traversal.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is that your `setNext` and `setPrev` functions take their parameters by value, so you get a *copy* of the nodes you declare in main.

If you want to proceed with this, pass those parameters by reference or by pointer. Passing by pointer would probably make more semantic sense and prevents this sort of accidental mistake.